# Efficient parallel Hadoop load from external sources?

Tags: bigdata, hadoop2

Lets assume that I've got a text file with `33000` lines, where each line is a `URL` pointing to a accessible `1 GB` `.gz` file, downloadable over the `HTTPS`. Lets also assume that I've got a `Hadoop 2.6.0` cluster consisting of `20` nodes. What is the fastest, yet still simple and elegant, parallel way how to load all of the files into the `HDFS`?

The best approach that I've been able to think so far is a bash script that will connect via the `SSH` to all of the other nodes running a series of the `wget` piped to the `HDFS` `put` commands. But in this scenario I am afraid of the concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java multithreading executor service . The sample example [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

You can read text file with URL . Read say 10 lines at at time and start downloading them in parallel using java multithreading. You can define number of thread to any number instead 10.

you can multithread  download file and then put it in HDFS using java HDFA APIs

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply :). If I understand your suggestion correctly, this multithreaded execution will be performed only on a single node. This means that 10 threads (for 10 parallel downloads) will be accessing possibly a single disk. I am not an expert into the disk IO scenarios but this looks to me as a bottleneck I am trying to avoid.